# Understanding tensorflow queues and cpu <-> gpu transfer

Tags: memory-management, gpu, tensorflow

After reading this github issue I feel like I'm missing something in my understanding on queues:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3009

I thought that when loading data into a queue, it will get pre-transferred to the GPU while the last batch is getting computed, so that there is virtually no bandwidth bottleneck, assuming computation takes longer than the time to load the next batch.

But the above link suggests that there is an expensive copy from queue into the graph (numpy <-> TF) and that it would be faster to load the files into the graph and do preprocessing there instead. But that doesn't make sense to me. Why does it matter if I load a 256x256 image from file vs a raw numpy array? If anything, I would think that the numpy version is faster. What am I missing?

Comment: If you feed in numpy arrays, there's an extra single-threaded memory copy to get data from Python to TensorFlow runtime. If you load from files using TensorFlow ops, there's no need for that copy since data stays in TF runtime.

Comment: What about pre-transferring to the GPU while the last batch is training. Then it wouldn't matter where the data is coming from, because it is now ready to go in TF when the last batch completes. Is that not how it works? At the end of the day you need to transfer from somewhere, either from disk or from the queue, but if it is asynchronous, should it matter?

Comment: BTW, in that issue you see that `QueueDequeueMany` is placed on /cpu:0 So using queue in that way does not transfer things onto GPU asynchronously

Comment: I think that makes things a lot clearer. So if we put the queue on /gpu:0 then my initial intuition is correct and that solves the bandwidth problem, assuming transfer is faster than computation?

Comment: I'm guessing Queue is CPU-only

Comment: Ah, gotcha. That puts everything into perspective. Feel free to put these comments in an answer, if you'd like :)

Comment: This seems to be the issue to follow: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5722

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no implementation of GPU queue, so it only loads stuff into main memory and there's no asynchronous prefetching into GPU. You could make something like a GPU-based queue using variables pinned to `gpu:0`

Comment: This feature tracks support for GPU queues https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5722

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/threading_and_queues/index.html) suggests that it is possible to pin a queue to a device:

> N.B. Queue methods (such as q.enqueue(...)) must run on the same device as the queue. Incompatible device placement directives will be ignored when creating these operations.

But the above implies to me that any variables one is attempting to enqueue should already be on the GPU.

[This](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2848#issuecomment-225960216) comment suggests it may be possible to use `tf.identity` to perform the prefetch.